# How to force google to reset sitelinks?

Tags: google, sitelinks

Google keeps displaying sitelinks from an old version of my website. Most of them lead to 404s, since the old website is offline. I tried to demote sitelinks individually but other sitelinks from old website are popping back... Weeks go but nothing change, is there a way to tell Google to speed up updating his data?

Also I already created an xml sitemap for the new website.

Comment: Why don't you just redirect those URLs to new pages?    Google isn't the only place that is going to be linking to your old URLs.   Any links you got from other sites will be broken for users for a long time if you don't redirect.   Most sites don't update their links frequently, if ever.   You are also losing lots of SEO value without redirects in place.

Comment: Because I just want to get ride of (some of) the old pages, they aren't related to my activity anymore. Lets say I'm a photographer and I used to work for weddings but now I am targeting more exiting things (magazine, etc.)

Comment: I have a feeling that if you removed your 404'd pages using the [google remove outdated content tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals?pli=1), then maybe the 404'd sitelinks would disappear faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change ([or demote](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleWebmasters/posts/b4WcMeLgbAL)) [sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en) anymore.

> At the moment, sitelinks are automated. We're always working to improve our sitelinks algorithms, and we may incorporate webmaster input in the future.

In order to prevent broken links in sitelinks, you could do the following:

1. 301 redirect from the old pages to the new ones
2. Submit a XML sitemap to Google Search Console
3. Build a good internal linking strategy
4. Use descriptive titles

Comment: Thanks. But what if I'd like to get ride of the old pages (because they aren't related to my activity anymore, at least some of them)?

Comment: The first action (301 redirects) will help you to get rid of the old pages.  Check this link: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

Google Shows Sitelinks According to Your Internal Linking Structure. It is the main factor in sitelinks. A webpage having more internal links on site are more chances to show in sitelinks.

you can: 
More internal linking on the website.
301 redirect on the same new pages.
Delete or no-index old pages from Google Console.
Submit Sitemap
Give some High-quality Backlinks to your webpages.